# Mount Android phone file system on Linux manually

Tags: mount, android

How can I bind my Android file system to my Linux machine, and modify it? When I plug in my Android device, it seems to use one USB interface but I couldn't find whre the mount point is. I checked `/mnt` but there is nothing.

Comment: shot answer adb can allow you to interact with your phone if you have the correct driver. but I wouldn't if I were you because you seems pretty rocky whit that and you rather search a bit before trying to do such a thing.

Comment: I tried adb and getting permission deny

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? @Kiwy You don't need any special driver, it's just generic USB + adb or USB mass storage.

Comment: ubuntu lite which is  work on the my usb.

Comment: `man simple-mtpfs`

Answer (score 1):

Some phones have icky USB storage interfaces, which don't work on Linux reliably (look [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52932/linux-fails-to-mount-android-device-in-usb-msc-mode) for example), others (e.g. my Samsung Galaxy with Android 4.3) seem not to offer USB access to their innards at all (nothing in the logs when plugging it in). Some need to be set up specially (allow USB in their configuration) to mount them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a newer smartphone that uses MTP/PTP protocol, I'm afraid you can't mount it to the filesystem and access it as a regular drive device with just a `mount` command - similar discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1157661/how-to-mount-an-android-smartphone-as-a-drive-in-windows).

To make this work, you need some kind of [virtual file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) tool. I believe [gvfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol#gvfs-mtp) should do the trick. To make this mounting automatic, a daemon has to be running in the background. Search for `gvfs`, `gvfs-mtp`, `gvfs-fuse`, `gvfs-deamons`, etc. in your package manager.

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol

https://superuser.com/questions/1157661/how-to-mount-an-android-smartphone-as-a-drive-in-windows

[Accessing MTP mounted device in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464767/accessing-mtp-mounted-device-in-terminal)

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs

Comment: It is unclear from your description how to used `gvfs` or alternatives.

Comment: It depends on distribution and system configuration. Try to search for gvfs manual in your distribution's wiki.

Answer (score 1):

[MTPFS](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/MTPfs) is likely what you want, it's [FUSE](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) based, but there is no reason that that wouldn't work (outside of device-specific issues)

After installing it :

Add yourself to `plugdev` group (to have the needed permissions)

```
gpasswd -a <USER_NAME> plugdev
```

Then, just run

```
mtpfs <empty folder>
```

To unmount :

```
fusermount -u <folder>
```

Comment: I could not find `mtpfs` for Ubuntu, but I found `jmtpfs`. When running that as normal user or as root I get: `No mtp devices found.` My phone "Select USB configuration" >  "Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)" and plugged in USB.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect to find a reliable solution that would work with USB
cable, the general trend in the industry is to go fully wireless.

The method I used for a couple of years and that works with various
Android devices and that works well and that doesn't require rooted
device is to use
[SimpleSSHD](http://www.galexander.org/software/simplesshd) on your
Android device and sshfs on your desktop Linux machine.

Install and setup SimpleSSHD on your Android device and use sshfs on desktop Linux machine like
that:

```
sshfs <PHONE_IP_ADDRESS>:<PATH_ON_ANDROID> <LOCAL_DIR>
```

For example, this is the command I use to mount Gallery from my Galaxy
S8 phone on my Slackware system:

```
$ mkdir gallery
$ sshfs phone:/sdcard/DCIM/Camera gallery
```

`phone` is an alias I defined in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host phone
     User shell
     Hostname Galaxy-S8
     Port 2222
```

Of course it requires your Android device and your Linux machine to be
in the same network.

Unmount local dir without root:

```
fusermount -u gallery
```

Last time I checked SimpleSSHD was a re-packaged Dropebar binary for
ARM.

Comment: `sshfs 192.168.1.230:/ phone/; ls phone/` gives `ls: reading directory 'phone/': Permission denied`.

Comment: You don't have a rooted device, you won't be able to access `/` like that. Rooting an Android device is a separate issue.

Comment: I do not want to root my device, but I want access to all the files I have access to. In other words: I want to be able to do a `find dir` and see all the files I have access to in `dir`.

Comment: That's possible only if you have a rooted device, normally you don't have access to `/` but to SD Card and several other directories.

Comment: You misunderstand me. The solution I am looking for should know this and give access to the dirs I have access to. I am not looking for a solution where you need to root your phone, but simply one that will give me the same access as any filemanager app on the phone already give.

Comment: so why did you specify `/` in your example if that's the directory you _cannot_ access? Specify the directory you can access such as `/storage/emulated/0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133487/discussion-between-ole-tange-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk).

Answer (score 0):

[ADBFS-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless) is another option, that works better for me than the other alternatives in this thread, when proper SSH is not setup to also work via USB-NET/JumpHost.

It's trivial to compile, the usual small dance:

```
git clone git://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless.git
cd adbfs-rootless
make
```

maybe install `libfuse-dev` `android-tools-adb` `build-essential` `git` `pkg-config` before.

Then mount your local usb-connected Android device with `./adbfs ~/droid`.

It's originally "configured" to only connect to local ADB devices via source, but can be trivially patched to connect to remotely usb-connected Android devices, using the remote ADBd on the USB-Host as "Jumphost".

You can also use it with USB-IP to connect to Android-devices hooked up to the USB of some WIFI-APs/Routers that way.

If you need to connect to ancient versions of Android, you may need to get statically compiled `adb` versions for different API-levels, and just make several `adbfs`-binaries with hardcoded paths to specific `adb`-versions.