# Accessing files on Android devices via a mounted file system

Tags: filesystems, mount, android

I want to mount my phone on my GNU/Linux machine. [Mount Android phone file system on Linux manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111870/mount-android-phone-file-system-on-linux-manually/687457#687457) mentions the Android file system and that is not exactly what I am looking for (which may be the reason I cannot really use the answers).

I tried `jmtpfs` but my phone does not show up as an MTP device.

The problem with accessing the Android file system is that as a normal user there are really only a few places that you have access to (e.g. you do not have read access to /).

I can access files on the phone using a filemanager installed on the phone. And it is these same files I want to access through a mount point. I imagine it could happen through FUSE that talks to a filemanager installed on the phone.

So I want to have the same access as any filemanager app running on the phone. No more (i.e. I do not want to root the phone), no less (I do not want to have to guess pathnames because some topdirs do not have -r permission). And I want this presented in a nice UNIX-file dir structure so I can do `find . -type f | parallel grep foo` or `cp -r * /mnt/backup` or `du`.

It would be fine if the dirs that I do not have access to where presented as empty read-only, so maybe `/mnt/phone/storage/emulated/0` would contain files, but `/mnt/phone/storage/` would be empty (apart from the dir `emulated`).

It would be OK to have to install an app on the phone. I can find some old projects that (try to?) give webdav support on the phone, and that might work, if there is a compatible FUSE webdav client for GNU/Linux.

So what I am really looking for, is someone who has the described setup running, and how this was done.

Comment: I've always used an FTP server on my Android phone for that, e.g. this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.swiftp (no ads, no unneeded features).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov This works very well. Thank you. One thing seems to be missing: I cannot see my SD-card.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @ArtemS.Tashkinov's comment:

Install "FTP Server (free)" on the phone. Open it.

```
sudo apt install curlftpfs
mkdir phone
curlftpfs ftp://ftp:ftp@192.168.1.231:2121 phone
```

Then you can use the dir `phone`.

The solution has 2 drawbacks:

- I cannot see how I can access the SD-card
- There is no caching (so if you access the file twice, you have to transfer it twice).